# Using a substitution without a leading space in reStructuredText

Tags: substitution, restructuredtext

In reStructuredText, this doesn't work (the `|reg|` substitution isn't done):

```
.. include:: <isonum.txt>

foo bar|reg| baz
================
```

This does work, but I don't want a space between `'bar'` and the `|reg|`:

```
.. include:: <isonum.txt>

foo bar |reg| baz
=================
```

How can I get substitutions recognized when they are immediately adjacent to a word?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
foo bar\ |reg| baz
```

Escaping the space with a backslash.